# how to get followers count from slideshare api?

Tags: api

I am working on social media project and wanted to fetch slideshare user followers count through API.
is it possible?
Can any one please help me because i am unable to get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](http://www.slideshare.net/developers/documentation) provided by slideshare, their [API](http://apiexplorer.slideshare.net/) does not include a method for getting follower count.

However, I think you can fetch it directly from user's page for which the URL is in the format:

```
http://www.slideshare.net/{userid}
```

Inspect the document and you will see the html code for printing out followers.

```
<div class="box sidebarPanels">
<a class="boxTitle follow spriteProfile followers j-followers" rel="nofollow" href="/{userid}/followers" title="Users following {user name}">Followers (0)</a>
<p style="font-size:13px;">No followers yet</p>
</div>
```

If working with .NET, one good library for getting data from HTML documents is [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

**[edit]**

For `PHP`, `HTML document` can be parser using [PHP Simple Html DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), also mentioned in this [article](https://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications).

Comment: I have updated my answer with PHP DOM parsing references.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Alexei... Appreciate